# How to use exclude folder option in 'Delete workspace before build starts' section?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'd like to exclude node_modules folder from deleting, but it removes all workspace.
I've already tried a lot of patterns with 'Apply pattern also on directories' option and without it.

Some of them: **/node_modules/**, */node_modules/*
I also found an issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12783, 
but seams like I'm trying to use wrong pattern.

Comment: In the comments of the JIRA you referenced there is an approach described that might help you: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12783?focusedCommentId=229874&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-229874

Comment: I've already understood how it works, thank you

Comment: then can you please post an answer to your question so that others will be able to reuse your solution?

Answer (score 11):

Sorry for the extra answer but nightmare's didn't get me all the way to the final result.  Because of [JENKINS-1278](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12783), if you want to exclude `node_modules` directories that are in child directories of the parent you have to exclude both the .git directories and the parent directory itself.

So let's say you have a directory layout like:

```
subModule1/
    node_modules/
    ...
subModule2/
    node_modules/
    ...
```

In this case you'll need to exclude the following directories:

```
**/.git/**
**/node_modules/**
subModule1
subModule2
```

If you do that, then everything inside of subModule1 and subModule2 will still get deleted (except the node_modules directory, of course).  And Git will still get updated with the latest changes even though it's not completely blown away each time.

It works for me, and I do not have "Apply pattern also on directories" checked.  It seems like that should be checked but according to that bug report you need to leave it unchecked.

Comment: my structure is folder/subfolder/subsub - I excluded **/subsub/**, subfolder and folder. It doesn't delete the contents of folder or subfolder. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @SriramIlango Unfortunately I switched to CircleCI shortly after this and haven't looked back.  I see in the JENKINS-1278 bug that somebody has a better work around with a plugin.  Maybe that's a better answer?

Comment: It works for me but I had to check "Apply pattern also on directories" to delete cleaned directories too.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is to use this syntax **/node_modules/**, but before you will exclude your folder, you need to exclude .git folder using the same format **/.git/**

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why do I need to exclude \*\*/.git/\*\*?  I want to remove everything except the node_modules.  That looks like it'll keep the .git directory which I'd rather blow away.

Comment: OK.  I get it now.  Once you have the \*\*/node_modules/\*\* part working then git won't clone the repo to a non-empty directory so everything gets wiped.

Comment: My problem was that I needed directories deleted, and if you check that option it deletes excluded subdirectories because it deletes the parent directory even though the child matches. My solution was to change the _includes_ to avoid any parent directories that should be preserved.