# Jenkins performance issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have Jenkins version 1.6.11 installed onto a windows server, the number of jobs configured are huge and the load is distributed among multiple Master & slave's. There are couple of issues occurring very frequently,

- The whole Jenkins UI becomes so slow, either Jenkins server needs to restarted or the whole server needs to restarted to bring it back to normal.
- Certain jobs are taking way too much time to load. To fix this, that particular job has to be abandoned and new ones has to be created for the same.

It would be really helpful if you could provide possible solutions for the two issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax **/node_modules/** to remove node modules folder, but before you do this, you should exclude .git folder using **/.git/**

Comment: to remove these folders please refer answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41728663/11063401

Comment: Can you please tell me how this is going to improve the performance?
I'm kind of confused.